# @IBAction de UIBarButtonItem dentro de una clase genérica no se ejecuta

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

the fact is I have created a generic cell that looks like this:

```
class GenericCell<T: ProtocolName>: UITableViewCell {

    // Properties ...

    var someThingINeed: T?

    private var toolbar: UIToolbar = {
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        toolbar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(didTapDone))
        let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(didTapCancel))

        cancelButton.tintColor = .red

        toolbar.setItems([cancelButton, flexibleSpace, doneButton], animated: false)

        return toolbar
    }()

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        if someThingINeed != nil {
            return toolbar
        }
        return nil
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var canResignFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    // Functions ...

    @objc private func didTapDone() {
        // do something...
        resignFirstResponder()
    }

    @objc private func didTapCancel() {
        // do something...
        resignFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

Entonces, para llamar la `inputView` de la celda, ejecuto este código desde el `UITableViewController` que maneja la tabla con ese tipo de celda:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Al ejecutar, ambas vistas, la `inputView` y la `inputAccessoryView` de la celda se muestran correctamente, pero cuando pulso en algún `UIBarButtonItem` (Cancelar u OK), los botones parecen responder y recibir el evento de pulsado, pero no se llama a ninguna acción.

Creo que la razón puede ser o que una clase genérica de Swift no puede actuar como "target" de una `UIView` o que una clase genérica de Swift no puede implementar funciones marcadas con `@objc`.

No sé qué más hacer, ya he intentado añadir la celda como delegada de la `UIToolbar` y ejecutando `toolbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` y nada ha funcionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, el problema era que había olvidado marcar la `UIToolbar` como `lazy`, por lo que no podía usar ni propiedades ni funciones de la clase.

No sé por qué Xcode no me avisó de esto... Creo que podría ser reportado.